# VBA:adding files with new version _vX, with separate dates

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am having trouble with creating new version, with the dates selected by the users.

So here I have 2 separate workbooks:

1) Macro - where the users will click the button and generate the macro

2) Report template - when the users click the macro, the figures will be generated into the templates, with the dates in the naming convention, and the version.
The report template naming convention looks like this : `BSLCT_DDMMYYYYG` where `DDMMYYYY` is the date, that the users will select in the report template.
So when the report is generated, it will SaveAs another file i.e `BSLCT_10072020G`.

The code I used to generate is as follow:

```
Sub Naming reports()
    Windows("BSTCT_DDMMYYYYG.xls").Activate
    Sheets("G.0(GenInfo)").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Path & "\BSLCT_" & REPORT_DATE & "G.xls"
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

where i define the `REPORT_DATE` before that.

Now, the users need to have a versioning in their file naming as well, which is something like `BSTCT_DDMMYYYYG_vX.xls`. So as long as the users run the macro, the macro will generate a new version, regardless of whether the date has already existed.

I managed to create a `_v1` using the following codes:

```
Sub version
    Windows("BSTCT_DDMMYYYYG.xls").Activate
    Sheets("G.0(GenInfo)").Select

    If InStr(ActiveWorkbook.Name, "_v") = 0 Then

    fileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name,
    InStr(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1) & "_v1." & ext
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (fileName)
    Else
    index = CInt(Split(Right(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) -  InStr(ActiveWorkbook.Name, "_v") - 1), ".")(0))
    index = index + 1
    fileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" &  Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name,InStr(ActiveWorkbook.Name, "_v") - 1) & "_v" & index & "." & ext
    End If
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (fileName)
End Sub
```

However, after generating the v1, I couldn't generate v1 onwards, because i need to activate the "`BSTCT_DDMMYYYYG.xls`" window to pick up the report date, this will then break my codes.

Also, while I am adding the version, at the same time i would like to get the `DDMMYYYY` into the naming too.

How can I do that?

I really appreciate your helps.

---

now i am trying to keep adding the newer version with the following code:
Sub SaveNewVersion()
    Dim fileName As String, index As Long, ext As String, sVersion As String
    arr = Split(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".")
    ext = arr(UBound(arr))
    sVersion = "_v"

```
Windows("BSLCT_DDMMYYYYG.xls").Activate
Sheets("G.0(GenInfo)").Select
If InStr(ActiveWorkbook.Name, "_v") = 0 Then

 fileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "" & Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, InStr(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1) & "_v1." & ext
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "\BSLCT_" & REPORT_DATE & "G" & sVersion & index & ".xls"
Else
    index = CInt(Split(Right(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - InStr(ActiveWorkbook.Name, "_v") - 1), ".")(0))
    index = index + 1
    fileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "" & Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, InStr(ActiveWorkbook.Name, "_v") - 1) & "_v" & index & "." & ext
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "\BSLCT_" & REPORT_DATE & "G " & sVersion & index & ".xls"
End If
ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

End Sub

but at first it keeps replacing my first version, and then saying that this line of code:
index = CInt(Split(Right(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - InStr(ActiveWorkbook.Name, "_v") - 1), ".")(0)) has syntax error.

Does anyone can help on this? I am really clueless where can I modify this.

Comment: I'd avoid of using `Activate` and `Select` method! They're useless till selection or activation is really needed.

Comment: BTW: use single procedure to set the name of workbook!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub SetNewName()

Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim sDate As String
Dim sVersion As String

sDate = Format(Date, "ddMMyyyy")
sVersion = "_v1"
Set wbk = Application.Workbooks("BSTCT_DDMMYYYYG.xls")
wbk.SaveAs ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & sDate & sVersion & ".xls"

End Sub
```

Comment: i tried the code, the sDate is referring to the date now. I need to refer the date to what users have chosen REPORT_DATE = Format(Range("F8").Value, "DDMMYYYY") so i tried wbk.SaveAs ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\BSLCT_" & REPORT_DATE &"" sVersion & ".xls" But it said syxtax error. Also, the sVersion = _v1, so after this do i use my method so whenever there is v1, it will auto populate v2?

Comment: As to the requirements, feel free to change the code to your needs. This is only an example. Syntax error is here: `&""`. You need space between `&` and `""`. BTW: `""` is reduntant.

Comment: thanks a lot. right now i am having trouble with the versioning, can you help clarifying where exactly i did wrong? thank you very much